# Faster alternatives to Characters object

Tags: excel, vba, strikethrough

I am required to extract passages of text from the contents of Excel cells in which the originator has essentially done a manual Track Changes using Strikethrough font. The passages are identifiable with certain character patterns, but I have to ignore Strikethrough characters to see them. The Strikethrough characters do not appear in regular locations within each cell, so are essentially randomly dispersed with normal font text.

I have achieved my goal using VBA for Excel, but the solution is extremely (and impracticably) slow. Having searched this site and the wider web for answers, it seems the use of the Characters object is to blame.

So my question is: has anyone found a way of parsing such text that does not involve the Characters object?

The sub I wrote to do the parsing is too long to post here, but following is some test code which uses the Characters object in a similar way. This takes 60 s to parse a cell with 3000 characters in it. At that speed, it would take 50 hours to process the entire spreadsheet I've been given.

```
Private Sub FindLineBreakChars(TargetCell As Excel.Range)

Dim n As Integer
Dim ch As String
Dim st As Boolean

If TargetCell.Cells.Count <> 1 Then
    Call MsgBox("Error: more or less than one cell in range specified.")
Else
    If IsEmpty(TargetCell.Value) Then
        Call MsgBox("Error: target cell is empty.")
    Else
        If Len(TargetCell.Value) = 0 Then
             Call MsgBox("Error: target cell contains an empty string.")
        Else
            'Parse the characters in the cell one by one.
            For n = 1 To TargetCell.Characters.Count
                ch = TargetCell.Characters(n, 1).Text
                st = TargetCell.Characters(n, 1).Font.Strikethrough
                If ch = vbCr Then
                    Debug.Print "#" & n & ": Carriage Return (vbCr)" & ", strikethrough = " & st & vbCrLf
                ElseIf ch = vbLf Then
                    Debug.Print "#" & n & ": Line Feed (vbLf)" & ", strikethrough = " & st & vbCrLf
                End If
            Next n
        End If
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what it is you're asking, can you not get the value of the cell and then split on carriage return to get an array of lines?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that simple, as I have to inspect the characters of each line as well. The above code is not what I'm trying to do, it was just a similar example of how I'm using the Characters object. I tried to edit my original post and upload an image of the desired before and after results, but am not allowed to load images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might meet your performance needs: it calls a function which parses the XML representation of the cell content, removes the struck-out sections, and returns the remaining text.

It will be much faster than looping over `Characters`

```
Sub Tester()

    Debug.Print NoStrikeThrough(Range("A1"))

End Sub

'Needs a reference to Microsoft XML, v6.0
'  in your VBA Project references
Function NoStrikeThrough(c As Range) '
    Dim doc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, rv As String
    Dim x As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode, s As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    'need to add some namespaces
    doc.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", _
                    "xmlns:ss='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet' " & _
                    "xmlns:ht='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'"
    doc.LoadXML c.Value(11) 'cell data as XML
    Set x = doc.SelectSingleNode("//ss:Data")'<< cell content
    Set s = x.SelectSingleNode("//ht:S")     '<< strikethrough
    Do While Not s Is Nothing
        Debug.Print "Struck:", s.Text
        x.RemoveChild s '<< remove struck section
        Set s = x.SelectSingleNode("//ht:S")
    Loop
    NoStrikeThrough = doc.Text
End Function
```

EDIT: here's another way to go at it, by breaking up the text into "blocks" and checking each block to see if it has any strikethrough.  How much faster this is than going character-by-character may depend on block size and the distribution of struck-out text in each cell.

```
Function NoStrikeThrough2(c As Range)
    Const BLOCK As Long = 50
    Dim L As Long, i As Long, n As Long, pos As Long, x As Long
    Dim rv As String, s As String, v

    L = Len(c.Value)
    n = Application.Ceiling(L / BLOCK, 1) 'how many blocks to check
    pos = 1                               'block start position
    For i = 1 To n
        v = c.Characters(pos, BLOCK).Font.Strikethrough
        If IsNull(v) Then
            'if strikethough is "mixed" in this block - parse out
            '  character-by-character
            s = ""
            For x = pos To pos + BLOCK
                If Not c.Characters(x, 1).Font.Strikethrough Then
                    s = s & c.Characters(x, 1).Text
                End If
            Next x
            rv = rv & s
        ElseIf v = False Then
            'no strikethrough - take the whole block
            rv = rv & c.Characters(pos, BLOCK).Text
        End If
        pos = pos + BLOCK 'next block position.
    Next i
    NoStrikeThrough2 = rv
End Function
```

EDIT2: if you need to make sure all newline characters are not struck out before processing the cell -

```
Sub ClearParaStrikes(c As Range)
    Dim pos As Long
    pos = InStr(pos + 1, c.Value, vbLf)
    Do While pos > 0
        Debug.Print "vbLf at " & pos
        c.Characters(pos, 1).Font.Strikethrough = False
        pos = InStr(pos + 1, c.Value, vbLf)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, wow. I tried your first suggestion and it was a tremendous improvement - about 2,000 times faster on the same 3,000 char cell I mentioned (and I timed it). I'm feeling pretty glad I signed up to this forum, because I don't think I would ever have found out about these XML routines otherwise. They don't appear in the Office Dev Center online help. Thankyou.

Comment: P.S. I had to add the Microsoft XML, v6.0 reference to the VBA workbench to get this to run.

Comment: Along with another fantastic discovery - regular expressions - the job is now essentially solved, but there is one last wrinkle. The line feeds in a cell that demarcate paragraphs of text are sometimes formatted with strikethrough. When they are deleted, this fouls my regex search ("(^|\n|/)\d+\.") for paragraph numbers, according to the way the client has written them. So, is there a way to modify NoStrikeThrough() so that it leaves line feeds alone? I've tried sifting through the MSXML documentation online, but there is a lot to learn when you're starting from scratch.

Comment: It's pretty straightforward to locate all of the vbLf characters and set their strikeout to False before proceeding to process the cell...

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the access to `Characters` is very slow, so your goal should be to reduce it's usage as much as possible.

I don't understand your requirement details, but the following code should get you an idea how you could speed up the code. It reads the content of a cell only once, split the text into separate lines, calculates the position of the single linefeed characters and look at that position for the formatting. As far as I know there is no way to access the formatting all at once, but now the access to the `characters`-object is reduced to one per line:

```
With TargetCell 
    Dim lines() As String, lineNo As Integer, textLen As Long
    lines = Split(.Value2, vbLf)
    textLen = Len(lines(0)) + 1
    For lineNo = 1 To UBound(lines)
        Dim st
        st = .Characters(textLen, 1).Font.Strikethrough
        Debug.Print "#" & textLen & ": LineFeed (vbLf) strikethrough = " & st
        textLen = textLen + Len(lines(lineNo)) + 1
    Next lineNo
End With
```

To my knowledge, Excel stores Linebreaks in a cell using just the LineFeed character, so the code is checking only that.

Comment: Additionally OP could cache the output to an array rather than use Debug.Print

Comment: Thanks all. The Split() suggestions looks like maybe my best bet. I wish I could load an image to clearly show an example of the challenge, but the website says I don't have enough points.