VBA Characters.Delete string over 255 characters
I want to delete parts of a string that is over 255 characters, while keeping the formatting in the cell the same. The question is related to this - the answer provided doesn't cover text that is over 255 characters, but since the issue is stand-alone, I think it merits its own question.
For demonstrative purposes, I want to delete 'lobortis' from the end of following text.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vulputate tellus enim, at sagittis felis lobortis at. Sed porttitor porttitor congue. Integer a ornare ante. Mauris a pellentesque tortor, non malesuada mauris. Duis rutrum lectus vitae lobortis non matrum 

Here's the code that does the trick for text less than 255 characters.
Is there a way to do this for text that is over 255 characters?
Sub ModifyTextSingleV2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    ' Define worksheet
    Set ws = Workbooks("workbook1").Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' The cell where the text is
    Set cell = ws.Cells(1, 1)
    
    ' Delete 'non matrum' from the cell << doesn't work, but would work if it were below 255 characters.
    cell.Characters(259, 10).Delete
End Sub


Your code does work - in that it will delete 8 characters after the 250th (so characters 251 to 258).  If you want to delete after 255 as asked in the question (is 250 in the code) try cell.Characters(255, Len(cell) - 255).Delete

@DarrenBartrup-Cook sorry, I realised that there's a small mistake in my code example. Indeed, the goal is to delete instances that occur after the 255th character. I've edited my post.

There is a confusion. Do you want to remove the characters at the end or from between as well?

I want to remove all characters between the starting position and the given length - this is what cell.Characters(259, 10).Delete achieves.
But the difficulty is that when you specify a piece of text +255 characters, the delete wont work.

Unfortunately, the Characters.Delete and Characters.Insert methods work when the argument is no more than 255 characters long, or you can delete the end of a longer string if there are no more than 255 characters left.
For longer texts, you can only set the Characters property of individual characters. Therefore, it would be necessary to build a "map" of character formatting and reapply the formatting after removing unnecessary characters.

Even if you map each character's properties (eg into a 2D array), accessing those properties is super-slow, so unless you only have a small number of cells to deal with it's going to take quite a while.  In my testing, mapping 6 properties from each character in a 400-character string took about 14-15sec

You guys are right. I managed to solve this issue with the answer that @DarrenBartrup-Cook provided in the linked post. However, it is very slow and practically inapplicable.

You can speed up that approach by only mapping character font properties which are not the same for all content.  If checking the cell font property doesn’t return null, you can skip the per-character checking

Spent far to long getting this right so I though I'd add it here.
Worth noting that if your cell content might contain the vbCrLf character combination, then the Characters collection will not "see" the first vbCr character, only the vbLf, and Characters(1).Text will be [# of vbCrLf]  shorter than the cell .Value property and things will get out of whack. "Standalone" vbCr are not a problem - this only occurs when vbCr is immediately followed by vbLf.
Option Explicit

Sub tester()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, c As Range
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting")
    Set c = ws.Range("A1")
    
    ws.Range("A8").Copy c  'copy from source cell (for testing only)
    ReplaceInFormattedCell c, "lobortis", ""
    Stop 'review and F5 to continue...
    
    ws.Range("A8").Copy c  
    ReplaceInFormattedCell c, "lobortis", "lobo"
    Stop
    
    ws.Range("A8").Copy c  
    ReplaceInFormattedCell c, "lobortis", "lobolobolobolobo"
    Stop
    
End Sub

Sub ReplaceInFormattedCell(c As Range, wd As String, wdRep As String)
    Dim map, txt, pos As Long, wdLen As Long, wdRepLen As Long, found As Boolean
    
    wdLen = Len(wd)
    wdRepLen = Len(wdRep)
    pos = InStr(1, c.Value, wd, vbTextCompare)
    Do While pos > 0
        found = True
        Debug.Print "Found at:", pos
        If IsEmpty(map) Then map = CharMap(c) 'need to create formatting map?
        txt = c.Value
        c.Value = Left(txt, pos - 1) & wdRep & Mid(txt, pos + wdLen, Len(txt))
        AdjustFontMap map, pos, wdLen, wdRepLen 'adjust map to reflect changes to cell content
        pos = InStr(pos + wdLen, c.Value, wd, vbTextCompare)
    Loop
    If found Then ApplyCharMap c, map 'apply map if we made any changes

End Sub

'Apply a font properties mapping array to cell `c`
' Optimized performance by applying properties to runs of characters
'   which share the same font property value
Sub ApplyCharMap(c As Range, map)
    Dim i, t, p, pNum As Long, v, prop, vCurr, start As Long, rl As Long
    t = Timer
    p = FontProps()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For pNum = 1 To UBound(p) + 1 'loop properties
        prop = p(pNum - 1)        'property name
        vCurr = Empty
        rl = 0
        For i = 1 To Len(c.Value)
            v = map(i, pNum)          'property value
            If v <> vCurr Then        'change in value?
                'previous run to apply?
                If rl > 0 Then CallByName c.Characters(start, rl).Font, prop, VbLet, vCurr
                vCurr = v 'reset propery value, start pos, and run length
                start = i
                rl = 1
            Else
                rl = rl + 1
            End If
        Next i
        'apply remaining run?
        If rl > 0 Then CallByName c.Characters(start, rl).Font, prop, VbLet, vCurr
    Next pNum
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Debug.Print "Applied map in", Timer - t
End Sub

'Map font properties per-character for cell `c` and return as a 2D array
'Optimize performance by:
'   (1) checking properties at the cell-level for non-null values
'   (2) checking "chunks" of characters where cell-level is Null (mixed format)
Function CharMap(c As Range)
    Const CHUNK As Long = 10
    Dim map, i, t, p, pNum, defProps, prop, txt, chars As Characters, v, r As Long, ub As Long
    
    t = Timer
    p = FontProps()
    ub = Len(c.Value)
    ReDim map(1 To ub, 1 To UBound(p) + 1)
    
    ReDim defProps(1 To UBound(p) + 1)
    For pNum = 1 To UBound(p) + 1 'check all font properties at the cell level
        prop = p(pNum - 1)
        defProps(pNum) = CallByName(c.Font, prop, VbGet)
    Next pNum
    
    For i = 1 To Len(c.Value) Step CHUNK
        'Debug.Print i
        Set chars = c.Characters(i, CHUNK)
        For pNum = 1 To UBound(p)
            prop = p(pNum - 1)
            v = defProps(pNum)
            'cell-level prop value is null, so check the chunk
            If IsNull(v) Then v = CallByName(chars.Font, prop, VbGet)
            
            'fill this part of the output array
            For r = i To i + (CHUNK - 1)
                If r > ub Then Exit For
                If Not IsNull(v) Then
                    map(r, pNum) = v 'same for all chars in this chunk
                Else
                    'mixed within chunk - read individually
                    map(r, pNum) = CallByName(c.Characters(r, 1).Font, prop, VbGet)
                End If
            Next r
        Next pNum
    Next i
    Debug.Print "Created map in", Timer - t
    CharMap = map
End Function

'font properties to track
Function FontProps()
    FontProps = Array("Bold", "Italic", "Underline", "Strikethrough", _
                      "Size", "Color", "Name")
End Function

'Adjust 2D array font character mapp to account for replacing a word at a specified location
'   map      = 2D array of character font properties
'   startPos = row where first character in search word was found
'   wdLen    = length of search word
'   repLen   = length of replacement word
Sub AdjustFontMap(ByRef map, startPos As Long, wdLen As Long, repLen As Long)
    Dim newMap, ub As Long, ubNew As Long, n As Long, i As Long, r As Long
    Dim iNew As Long, diff As Long, adding As Boolean, editPos As Long
    
    diff = repLen - wdLen     '# of rows to add (diff>0) or remove (diff<0)
    If diff = 0 Then Exit Sub 'no work to do....
    
    ub = UBound(map, 1) 'current size
    ubNew = ub + diff   'new size
    adding = diff > 0     'adding row (or removing)
    editPos = IIf(adding, startPos + wdLen, startPos + repLen) 'changes begin here
    
    ReDim newMap(1 To ubNew, 1 To UBound(map, 2)) 'size output array
    
    For r = 1 To editPos - 1 'before any changes
        CopyRow map, r, newMap, r
    Next r
    
    i = editPos
    iNew = editPos
    'handle changes
    For n = 1 To Abs(diff)
        If adding Then
            CopyRow newMap, iNew - 1, newMap, iNew 'copy previous row
            iNew = iNew + 1
        Else
            i = i + 1   'removing, so just increment row index
        End If
    Next n
    
    For r = iNew To ubNew 'rest of rows
        CopyRow map, i, newMap, r
        i = i + 1
    Next r
    map = newMap 're-assign reference
End Sub

'copy a row from one 2D array to another (or to the same array)
Sub CopyRow(arrSrc, rwSrc As Long, arrDest, rwDest As Long)
    Dim c As Long
    For c = 1 To UBound(arrSrc, 2)
        arrDest(rwDest, c) = arrSrc(rwSrc, c)
    Next c
End Sub

My source cell (A8 in Sub tester):


I love the use of CallByName, very clever.  I also  liked you comment on font property no returning  null.  I started out mapping by changed my approach because I'm generating test data using vbNewLine (vbCr & vbLf)  the characters property converts it to vbLF.  This causes the characters length to be different from the cell text length until you edit the cell and then the vbCr are dropped altogether.  I'll be posting an answer in a couple of hours.

@TinMan - good point.  I did not test with vbCr/vbLf or vbCrLf.  I did have a further optimization for reading character font properties here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61654127/faster-alternatives-to-characters-object but had not remembered it before writing the code above, so did not fold it in there.

OMG,  I never knew about XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet.  I'm actually working on an XML solution now.

Added in an optimization for checking font properties by "chunk" when building the font property map in CharMap.  That improves performance by about 4-5 fold.

Geez.. I also "Spent far to long getting this right".  I just posted my solution that parses the Range XML.

Optimized ApplyCharMap and now much faster - applying font properties to runs of characters is much faster.

Please post this on CodeReview.  It deserves more exposure than you'll get here.  If it is okay with you, I would also like to refactor it.

@TinMan - I don't spend any time on Code Review, since there's almost no VBA posts there on a day-to-day basis.  But feel free to refactor - I admit i spent more time getting it working than on the structure, and I still need to put something in there to account for Characters.Text reducing vbCrLf (2 characters) down to vbLf (only 1)

Please checkout my new answer where I used a Shape as an editor.  I've seen you use runs of characters before in your other posts and assume that you tried it (or MS Word) for this one.

Add Funky Formatting
Sub FormatA2()
    FormatRangeChars [A2]
End Sub

Sub FormatRangeChars(Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim n As Long
    Dim Color As Long
    Dim FontSize As Long
    Dim Bold As Boolean
    Dim Italic As Boolean
    Dim Underline As Long
    Randomize
    For n = 1 To Target.Characters.Count - 2 Step 8
        Color = RGB(Int(255 * Rnd), Int(255 * Rnd), Int(255 * Rnd))
        FontSize = Int((16 - 8 + 1) * Rnd + 8)
        Bold = (Rnd > 0.5)
        Italic = (Rnd > 0.5)
        Underline = IIf(Rnd > 0.5, xlUnderlineStyleSingle, xlUnderlineStyleNone)
        FormatChars Target, n, 3, Color, FontSize, Bold, Underline, Italic
    Next
End Sub

Sub FormatChars(Target As Range, StartChar As Long, Length As Long, Optional Color As Long = -1, Optional FontSize As Variant = Null, Optional Bold As Boolean = False, Optional Underline As Variant = xlUnderlineStyleNone, Optional Italic As Boolean = False)
    With Target.Characters(StartChar, Length).Font
        If Color <> -1 Then .Color = Color
        If Not IsNull(FontSize) Then .Size = FontSize
        .Bold = Bold
        .Italic = Italic
        .Underline = Underline
    End With
End Sub

Code
There are two Public Sub to manipulate the characters in a Range of contigious cells:


DeleteCharactersFromRange: Simply removes a range of character from every targeted cell
RemoveWordFromRange:  Removes every occurrence of a word from every targeted cell


Option Explicit

Public Function DeleteCharactersFromRange(ByRef ContiguousRange As Range, ByVal Start As Long, ByVal Length As Long)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set xmlDoc = GetXMLDocumentFromRange(ContiguousRange)
    
    Dim Map As Collection
    Set Map = GetXMLCellsTextNodes(ContiguousRange, xmlDoc)

    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In ContiguousRange
        DeleteNodeChars Map(Cell.Address), Start, Length
    Next
    
    PasteXMLDoc ContiguousRange, xmlDoc
    
End Function

Public Sub RemoveWordFromRange(ByRef ContiguousRange As Range, ByVal Word As String, CompareMethod As VbCompareMethod)
    Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set xmlDoc = GetXMLDocumentFromRange(ContiguousRange)
    
    Dim Map As Collection
    Set Map = GetXMLCellsTextNodes(ContiguousRange, xmlDoc)

    Dim Start As Long
    Dim Text As String
    
    Dim CellTextNodes As Collection
    
    For Each CellTextNodes In Map
        Start = 0
        If CellTextNodes.Count > 0 Then
            Text = ConCatTextNodeCollection(CellTextNodes)
            Do While InStr(1, Text, Word, CompareMethod) > 0
                Start = InStr(1, Text, Word, CompareMethod)
                DeleteNodeChars CellTextNodes, Start, Len(Word)
                Text = ConCatTextNodeCollection(CellTextNodes)
            Loop
        End If
    Next
    
    PasteXMLDoc ContiguousRange, xmlDoc
End Sub

Private Function ConCatTextNodeCollection(ByRef Map As Collection) As String
    If Map.Count = 0 Then Exit Function
    Dim Data As Variant
    ReDim Data(1 To Map.Count)
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = 1 To Map.Count
        Rem Child.data is used because Child.Text omits lead spaces and Child.XML is readonly
        Data(n) = Map(n).Data
    Next
    ConCatTextNodeCollection = Join(Data, "")
End Function

Private Function DeleteNodeChars(ByRef Map As Collection, ByVal Start As Long, ByVal Length As Long)
    Dim TextNode As IXMLDOMText
    Dim CurrentPos As Long

    Dim n As Long
    Dim Cursor As Long

    For n = 1 To Map.Count
        Set TextNode = Map(n)
        Rem Child.data is used because Child.Text omits lead spaces and Child.XML is readonly

        Dim NodeLength As Long
        NodeLength = Len(TextNode.Data)
        
        If CurrentPos + NodeLength < Start Then
            CurrentPos = CurrentPos + NodeLength
        Else
            Cursor = Start - CurrentPos - 1
            If Cursor < 0 Then Cursor = 0
            
            TextNode.deleteData Cursor, Length
            Length = Length - (NodeLength - Len(TextNode.Data))

            Rem If all characters have been deleted, exit the loop
            If Length <= 0 Then Exit For
            CurrentPos = CurrentPos + NodeLength
            
        End If
    Next n
End Function

Rem Recursive function to gather all text from nodes, even with nested elements
Private Function GetAllText(ByRef Node As IXMLDOMNode) As String
    Dim Child As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim Text As String
    Text = ""

    Rem Loop through all child nodes
    For Each Child In Node.ChildNodes
        If Child.NodeType = NODE_TEXT Then
            Rem  Child.XML is used because Child.Text omits lead spaces
            Text = Text & Child.XML
        Else
            Rem If the child node has its own children, recurse into it
            Text = Text & GetAllText(Child)
        End If
    Next Child
    
    GetAllText = Text
End Function

Private Function GetCellTextNodes(ByRef Node As IXMLDOMNode, Optional ByRef Map As Collection) As Collection
    If Map Is Nothing Then Set Map = New Collection
    Dim Child As IXMLDOMNode

    Rem Loop through all child nodes
    For Each Child In Node.ChildNodes
        If Child.NodeType = NODE_TEXT Then
           Map.Add Child
        Else
            Rem If the child node has its own children, recurse into it
            GetCellTextNodes Child, Map
        End If
    Next Child
    
    Set GetCellTextNodes = Map
End Function

Private Function GetXMLCellsTextNodes(ByRef Target As Range, ByRef xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60) As Collection
    Dim RowIndex As Long, ColumnIndex As Long
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim Map As New Collection
    Dim RowNode As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim CellNode As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim DataNode As IXMLDOMElement
    
    For Each Cell In Target
        Map.Add New Collection, Cell.Address
    Next
    
    Dim Key As String
    
    Rem Loop through rows using the 'ss' namespace prefix
    For Each RowNode In xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//ss:Row")
        Rem The first Row's ss:Index is null
        RowIndex = IIf(IsNull(RowNode.getAttribute("ss:Index")), 1, RowNode.getAttribute("ss:Index"))
        Rem Loop through cells
        For Each CellNode In RowNode.SelectNodes("ss:Cell")
            Rem The Cell's  ss:Index in a Row is null
            ColumnIndex = IIf(IsNull(CellNode.getAttribute("ss:Index")), 1, CellNode.getAttribute("ss:Index"))
            Key = Target(RowIndex, ColumnIndex).Address ': Debug.Print Key
            For Each DataNode In CellNode.SelectNodes("ss:Data")
                GetCellTextNodes DataNode, Map(Target(RowIndex, ColumnIndex).Address)
            Next DataNode
            
        Next CellNode
    Next RowNode
    Set GetXMLCellsTextNodes = Map
End Function

Private Function GetXMLDocumentFromRange(ByRef Target As Range) As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim xmlString As String
    xmlString = Target.Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet)

    Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    
    Rem Load the XML string into the DOMDocument
    xmlDoc.LoadXML xmlString
    
    Rem Set the namespace for the 'ss' prefix used in the XML
    xmlDoc.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:ss='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet'"
    
    Set GetXMLDocumentFromRange = xmlDoc
End Function

Private Sub PasteXMLDoc(ByRef Target As Range, ByRef xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60)
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim FileNum As Integer
    Dim FilePath As String
    
    Rem Create a temporary file to store the XML content
    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    TempFileName = "TempXMLFile.xml"
    FilePath = TempFilePath & TempFileName
    
    Dim Content As String
    Content = CleanXMLString(xmlDoc)

    Rem Write the XML content to a temporary file
    FileNum = FreeFile
    Open FilePath For Output As FileNum
    Print #FileNum, Content
    Close FileNum
 
    Rem Open the XML file as a workbook
    With Workbooks.OpenXML(FilePath, xlXMLSpreadsheet)
        .Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Copy Target.Cells(1, 1)
        .Close False
    End With
    Rem Delete temporary file
    Kill FilePath
End Sub

Private Function CleanXMLString(ByRef xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60) As String
    Dim Content As String
    Content = Replace(xmlDoc.XML, vbCrLf, "&#10;")
    Content = Replace(Content, vbCr, "&#10;")
    Content = Replace(Content, vbLf, "&#10;")
    
    CleanXMLString = Content
End Function

Test
Sub Prep_ComplexExample()
    Range("A2").Copy [C2]
    Range("A2").Copy [E2]
End Sub

Public Sub Test_RemoveWordFromRange()
    Prep_ComplexExample
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim t As Double: t = Timer
    RemoveWordFromRange Range("C2:F2"), "the", VbCompareMethod.vbTextCompare
    Debug.Print "RemoveWordFromRange: "; Timer - t; " secs"
End Sub

Public Sub Test_DeleteCharactersFromRange()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Prep_ComplexExample
    Dim t As Double: t = Timer
    DeleteCharactersFromRange Range("C2:F2"), 1, 3
    Debug.Print "DeleteCharactersFromRange: "; Timer - t; " secs"
End Sub

Results
Execution Time

RemoveWordFromRange Results:

RemoveWordFromRange Range("C2:F2"), "the", VbCompareMethod.vbTextCompare

In this test I removed the word "the" from Range("C2:F2"),

Notes
I originally was pulling the XML from clipboard until I seen Tim Williams post where he used: Range.Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet).
The XML result uses the Unicode (UTF-16) character set,  Support for other characters could be added to CleanXMLString().

Nice solution !

Thanks @TimWilliams.  Hands down, you have the best answer.  I learned a lot! Particularly how to get different types of data from the clipboard.   I think that there about 32 formats, including  HTML, CSV, Rich Text and XML, in the clipboard when we copy a range.

CopyToAndReplace is a simple example of using a Shape as a textext editor.
The Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Replace makes it easy to replace one or more substrings and to match the case without losing the character formatting.
Function Replace(FindWhat As String, ReplaceWhat As String, [After As Long], [MatchCase As MsoTriState = msoFalse], [WholeWords As MsoTriState = msoFalse]) As TextRange2

Note: The code was designed to take a Source range of one or more cells, edit the content and transfer the complete contents to a single cell while keeping the formatting.
Code
Option Explicit
Rem CopyToAndReplace Range("A1:C2"), Range("A10"), "who", "whom"
Rem [ShapeEditor.bas](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nCPePXcQggBeNtf5V70PSN9eWsVDS4kj/view?usp=sharing)  I thought that I had something here but there is no way to handle the line breaks.

Sub CopyToAndReplace(Source As Range, Target As Range, SubString As String, Replacement As String)
    Dim Editor As Shape
    Set Editor = RangeToShape(Source)
            
    With Editor.TextFrame2
        Do While InStr(.TextRange, SubString) > 0
            .TextRange.Replace SubString, Replacement
        Loop
        .TextRange.Copy
    End With
            
    ShapeToRange Target, Editor
            
    Editor.Delete
End Sub
        
Function RangeToShape(Source As Range) As Shape
    Const ChunkSize As Long = 10
            
    Dim Editor As Shape
    Set Editor = Source.Worksheet.Shapes.AddTextEffect(PresetTextEffect:=msoTextEffect31, Text:=" ", _
        FontName:="+mn-lt", FontSize:=8, FontBold:=10, FontItalic:=msoFalse, Left:=200, Top:=0)
    Editor.Height = Source.Height: Editor.Width = Source.Width
            
    Dim TextRange As TextRange2
    Set TextRange = Editor.TextFrame2.TextRange
    Source.Copy
    TextRange.Paste
    

    Dim Offset As Long, c As Long, Length As Long
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim Result As Variant
    
    Rem Remove NBSP:  These are only inserted when an empty cell's formatted (Background or Border) differ from the rest of the Source
    For c = TextRange.Characters.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Asc(TextRange.Characters(c, 1)) = 160 Then TextRange.Characters(c, 2).Delete
    Next
    
    For Each Cell In Source
        If Cell.Characters.Count > 0 Then
            If Not IsNull(Cell.Font.Size) Then
                TextRange.Characters(Offset + 1, Cell.Characters.Count).Font.Size = Cell.Font.Size
            Else
                For c = 1 To Cell.Characters.Count
                    Length = IIf(c + ChunkSize - 1 > Cell.Characters.Count, Cell.Characters.Count - c + 1, ChunkSize)
                    Result = Cell.Characters(c, Length).Font.Size
                    If IsNull(Result) Then
                        TextRange.Characters(c + Offset, 1).Font.Size = Cell.Characters(c, 1).Font.Size
                    Else
                        TextRange.Characters(c + Offset, Length).Font.Size = Result
                        c = c + Length - 1
                    End If
                Next
            End If
            Offset = Offset + Cell.Characters.Count + 1
            TextRange.Characters(Offset, 1).Text = vbVerticalTab
        End If
    Next
            
    Set RangeToShape = Editor
End Function
        
Sub ShapeToRange(Target As Range, Shape As Shape, Optional NewLineDelimiter As String = "")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Run As TextRange2
    With Shape.TextFrame2
        Target.Value = Replace(.TextRange.Text, vbVerticalTab, vbLf)
        For Each Run In .TextRange.Runs
            With Target.Characters(Run.Start, Run.Length).Font
                .Bold = Run.Font.Bold
                .Color = Run.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB
                .Italic = Run.Font.Italic
                .Name = Run.Font.Name
                .Size = Run.Font.Size
                .Strikethrough = Run.Font.Strikethrough
                .Subscript = Run.Font.Subscript
                .Superscript = Run.Font.Superscript
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
    
Sub PrintAsc(Text As String)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim AscValue As Integer
    
    For i = 1 To Len(Text)
        AscValue = Asc(Mid(Text, i, 1))
        Debug.Print i, AscValue
    Next i
End Sub

TextRange2 Properties
The Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange type is TextRange

Test
CopyToAndReplace Range("A1:C2"), Range("A4"), "b", "c"



Nice idea - I was focused on "in place" fixes, and did not try out any other approaches
